# Calculating difference between dates

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help in how to subtract the `last_modified` and the `final_manuscript_date` in the following array:

```
Array ( 
    [chapters_id] => 10736 
    [last_modified] => 2010-12-21 15:01:55 
    [steps_id] => 3 
    [sub_step_id] => 0 
    [steps_position] => 1 
    [final_manuscript_date] => 2010-09-27 
)
```

So I can in this case get a value of N days between the dates 2010-12-21 and 2010-09-27?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply do:

```
$diff = strtotime($arr["final_manuscript_date"]) - strtotime($arr["last_modified"]);
$days = $diff / 84600; // to get # of days, you can round them off or use ceil/floor
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5.3+:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2010-09-27");
$date2 = new DateTime("2010-12-21");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->d //returns days.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked strtotime?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php